# Assigning a random integer value to an array item

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, html5-canvas

(HTML5 Canvas, JavaScript) Hi, so I have this array:

```
        var chestArray = new Array(9);
        chestArray[0] = "./assets/chest.png";

        var chest = new Image();
        chest.onload = function () {
            ctx.drawImage(chest, 150, 280, 200, 177);
            ctx.drawImage(chest, 320, 280, 200, 177);
            ctx.drawImage(chest, 490, 280, 200, 177);
            ctx.drawImage(chest, 150, 420, 200, 177);
            ctx.drawImage(chest, 320, 420, 200, 177);
            ctx.drawImage(chest, 490, 420, 200, 177);
            ctx.drawImage(chest, 150, 560, 200, 177);
            ctx.drawImage(chest, 320, 560, 200, 177);
            ctx.drawImage(chest, 490, 560, 200, 177);
        };
        chest.src = chestArray[0];
```

and I also have a button which generates a random number between 0 and 8:

```
    function randomBox() {
        alert('it worked! ' + Math.floor(Math.random() * chestArray.length));
    }
```

Whatever random number is generated, I then want it to perform a task with the correct chest, but first I need a way to assign each of the 9 chests in the above array to its numbers ordered 0 to 8. What is the easiest way to do this? I thought I may be able to assign each chest individually within the array, but whether I was doing something wrong, it did not work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why? What are you doing? This is certainly X/Y problem. Your question is poorely worded but I am guessing you want to draw all chests, and then do "something" to a random chest, is this correct?

Comment: Yes. I have the chests drawn already.

Comment: and what do you want to do to the random chest?

Comment: It will display an image. Let me make this a bit clearer since my question wasn't worded very well. I have 9 boxes. They're in an array, all displayed and ready. I have a button. I click the button, it gives me a random number between 0 - 8. Let's say the number it gives me is 5 - I want my program to say okay, that's box number 6. I need a way of linking the two things so that I can then make the box display an image when this happens.

Comment: So you want to display 9 images, and for a random one draw a particular image, but for the rest draw a chest image? The first step would be to load 2 images, the chest and this *other* image. Then you want to read DILP's answer to place your 9 image objects/chests in an array. Before drawing the images, you will want to use the random integer you generated to change the src for the array item to the *other* image (not a chest). See my answer to understand how to assign a value to a random item in an array.

Answer (score 0):

By putting the items into an array to start you will be able to reference them later. I don't quite know what you're going for but this might help:

```
function draw() {
  var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = "https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/5395/backdrop.png";
  var chestArr = [
    {image:img,dx:150,dy:280,dWidth:200,dHeight:177},
    {image:img,dx:320,dy:280,dWidth:200,dHeight:177},
    {image:img,dx:490,dy:280,dWidth:200,dHeight:177},
    {image:img,dx:150,dy:420,dWidth:200,dHeight:177},
    {image:img,dx:320,dy:420,dWidth:200,dHeight:177},
    {image:img,dx:490,dy:420,dWidth:200,dHeight:177},
    {image:img,dx:150,dy:560,dWidth:200,dHeight:177},
    {image:img,dx:320,dy:560,dWidth:200,dHeight:177},
    {image:img,dx:490,dy:560,dWidth:200,dHeight:177}
  ];

    chestArr.forEach(function(chest){
      ctx.drawImage(chest.image, chest.dx, chest.dy, chest.dWidth, chest.dHeight);
    });

}
```

This assumes you have an `"onload=draw()"` and the canvas element set in your markup.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. I already have the items in an array, what I am trying to do is have something happen to a random array item (in this case a chest) when I click my button.

Comment: your question shows you do not assign your chests into an array. new Array(9) creates 9 undefined values in the array and you assign a string to the first item.

Comment: The chests are in an array, as I have them drawn on the Canvas using the X, Y, Width, Height values. They are all appearing. The (9) is there to give range to the random generator.

Comment: No, they are not *in* an array. You are calling ctx.drawImage 9 times, and the array in your code contains 8 `undefined` values and 1 `string` value.

Answer (score 0):

To assign a value such as a number to an array item, use square brackets with the zero-based index of the item you want to assign a value to.

For example:

```
const arr = ["foo", "bar", "baz"];
arr[1] = true;
//now arr contains ["foo", true, "baz"];
```

To assign your chests into an array, see [DILP's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49583235/5674976) on a way to do this.

Here you can assign `true` to a random item of a 9 item array:

```js
function randomInteger(max){
  return Math.floor(Math.random()*max);
}
//create an array of undefined values of length 9
const arr = new Array(9);

//assign true to a random array item (do "something" with this random array item)
arr[randomInteger(arr.length)] = true;

console.log(arr);
```